# Get mutliple elements to show inline with text in css

Tags: html, css

I need to design a paragraph that looks like this

[image]

I'm having problem aligning all the elements so they like that, the main problem is making the share link go bellow the pic while also having the text wrap both of them inline.

I've tried various combinations, but no luck so far.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="resources/test.png" height="100" width="100">
    <label style="position: relative;bottom:0;left:0;">Share</label>
  </div>
  <label style="display:inline-block; font-size: 150%;">Video Title</label>
  <span>
             sdfddd dddd ddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddd dds d sd fsdfsd fsd fsghf gjfghfg
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to `float` the second div element to the left, and give it a width matching the image's. And please go read some tutorials on the fundamentals of CSS layouting - this is something pretty basic you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) the div where there is the image and the link. Then make the link (or the image) `display:block`  so that they don't stay at the same line.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;max-width:300px;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="100" width="100">
    <label style="display:block">Share</label>
  </div>
  <label style="display:inline-block; font-size: 150%;">Video Title</label>
  <span>
             Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume
        </span>
</div>
```